# Removing CR/LF at end of file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file, carriage-return

I've searched for a solution to this, but any I've found are either doing much more than I need or are not exactly what I want.

I have files I want to append to. I need to append to the end of the last line but they all have a carriage return and so I'll end up appending to the new line if I just append as normal.

All I want is to make a subroutine that takes a file path and removes the CR/LF at the end of it, no more, no less. Any help pointing me at a solution to this would be appreciated. I'm surprised there isn't a built in function to do this.

Comment: Have you got any code, showing how you are reading and writing the file?

Comment: Not yet. I need rid of the carriage return before I can do anything. Writing to the file is trivial. I just need the carriage return gone, and I'll write to the file later. The tasks are going to be separate.

Comment: Global idea would be to open file as Read/Write, place the pointer at the last two characters (CR+LF is two characters) and start writing from there. That would get rid of the last new line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Dim crString = Environment.NewLine '= vbCrLf
    Dim crBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(crString)
    Dim bytesRead(crBytes.Length -  1) as Byte
    Dim iOffset As Integer = 0
    Dim stringRead As String 

    Using fs = File.Open("G:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)      
        While iOffset < fs.Length    
            fs.Seek(- (crBytes.Length + iOffset), SeekOrigin.End)
            fs.Read(bytesRead,0, crBytes.Length)
            stringRead = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesRead)
            If stringRead = crString Then
                fs.SetLength(fs.Length - (crBytes.Length  * iOffset + 1))
                Exit While
             End If
            iOffset += 1
        End While
    End Using
```

I open the text file as `FileStream` and set its position to the end of the file - length of the carriage return string.

I then read the current bytes while decreasing the offset until I found a carriage return or the eof has been reached.

If a CR has been found I remove it and everything what comes after. 
If you don´t want that just remove the loop and check the eof only. 
But there could be some `vbNullString` at the eof that´s why I´m using the loop.

**Please note** that I used `UTF8` encoding in my example. If you have other encodings you have to adapt it accordingly.

test.txt before run:

[image: Before]

test.txt after code snippet run:

[image]

**EDIT**: `fs.SetLength` part was wrong in case of last character in file was not a CR.

Comment: Fabulous stuff. Thanks very much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Please check if it works with *faulty* or *irregular* text files (if this oculd occur in your environemnt). I have only tested it rudimentary. Also see my edit.

Comment: It works perfectly with the files I'm using, which should always be of the same form. If they're not, that will be dealt with before this script touches them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found `String.Replace(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(),"")` works.

Probably better ways to do it as well!

Comment: It's actually a file and not a string. Thanks for the suggestion though.